# Send email using CDO no longer working

Tags: email, ms-access, vba, cdo.message

since last week, I am no longer able to send email via gmail's smtp server. I get the error " -2147220973 the transport failed to connect to the server" whenever I try to send email. However, if I try using my another network (ex. my mobile broadband) it works.
Below is my code for sending email.

```
    Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set cdoconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    cdoconf.Load -1 ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set cdoFields = cdoconf.Fields

    With cdoFields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "example@gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "abc"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 465
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout")  = 60
        .Update
    End With
```

What is the possible problem? Thank you.

Comment: I actually had similar problems today, until I realized that I needed to add the line to set `smtpusessl=true`, and then it worked for me... Perhaps for you you could send emails via a proxy e.g. http://smtpproxy.codeplex.com/ (using ports 25 and with `smtpusessl=false`) and then let the proxy forward to gmail